# How to get an Object from Reast Easy Preprocessor to PostProcessor?

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I have a scenario where I need to implement a mechanism to show in log the time taken for my rest api to execute. I am planning to have a PreProcessorInterceptor containing something like

`long  startTime = system.currenttimemillis()`

And in PostProcessInterceptor I will get the endTime and planning to subtract the startTime from endTime.
How can I get the starttime in my PostProcessInterceptor ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) and a [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) you could add an property to the request:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class TimerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());        
    }

}

@Provider
public class TimerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimerResponseFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        long startTime = (long) requestContext.getProperty("foo.bar.startTime");
        LOG.info("Execution took {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this with the below jar  javax.ws.rs-api.2.0-m09. Instead of having the annotations I added the provider details in the web.xml.
Also I am not able to find the annotation PreMatching. The requests are not going inside the ContainerRequestFilter

Comment: Why are you using a milestone when there is a released version? You'll find `@PreMatching` in 2.0. Also please try with the annotations.